# JAXB and Polymorphism

Tags: xml, jaxb, polymorphism, cxf, marshalling

I am having trouble getting the following class structure marshalled by Java's JAXB implementation. I have an abstract identifier class, which has a value.

It is important to me, that the value be represented as an attribiute.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({
    AbstractIDInt.class
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "AbstractID")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public abstract class AbstractID {

    @XmlAttribute
    abstract Object getValue ();
}
```

And, here is a class that extends the abstract id class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "AbstractIDInt")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class AbstractIDInt extends AbstractID {
    Integer value;

    Integer getValue () {
        return value;
    }

    public void setvalue (Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Currently Java's JAXB implementation just throws an exception if you try to marshall something of the type AbstractID.

Is this violating something in the JAXB standard or is the Java's implementation of JAXB broken?

Answer (score 3):

There may be a bug with the implementation of JAXB included in the JDK.  Using JDK 1.6.0_29 I get the exception that you are probably seeing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.<init>(AttributeProperty.java:56)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:479)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    at forum9382200.Demo.main(Demo.java:9)
```

Running the same demo code with [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) I get the following output (I'm the MOXy lead):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AbstractIDInt value="1"/>
```

The following is the demo code that I used:

```
package forum9382200;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AbstractID.class);

        AbstractIDInt abstractIDInt = new AbstractIDInt();
        abstractIDInt.setvalue(1);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(abstractIDInt, System.out);
    }

}
```

**For More Infomration:**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

---

**UPDATE**

If you need to use the JAXB RI included in the Java SE you could try the following:

**AbstractID**

Mark the parent class as `@XmlTransient`:

```
package forum9382200;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlSeeAlso({
    AbstractIDInt.class
})
@XmlTransient
public abstract class AbstractID {

    abstract Object getValue ();
}
```

**AbstractIDInt**

Annotate the `value` property on the subclass:

```
package forum9382200;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "AbstractIDInt")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class AbstractIDInt extends AbstractID {
    Integer value;

    @XmlAttribute
    Integer getValue () {
        return value;
    }

    public void setvalue (Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I can annotate AbstractID to get it to work with Java's implementation of JAXB? I use JAXB through CXF to generate a WSDL. I need the code generated from the WSDL to generate AbstractID with the getValue() method.

Comment: @prmatta - I have added an update that may work with the JAXB RI.

Comment: I think the issue with this is that in the generated WSDL, and in the code generated from the WSDL, AbstractID will now be an empty class, and AbstractIDInt has the field "value". So, someone who want to get a value would first need to cast to AbstractIDInt. This is not ideal - since it isn't possible to know which derived type to cast to. I need a way that the field "value" needs to be inherited from AbstractID. Any other ideas?